# IEnumerable works but Type or namespace IQueryable could not be found - MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, ienumerable, iqueryable

I'm using MVC5 and trying to make a simple list.  I used the scaffolding, which creates the model as IQueryable in the Controller, and IEnumerable in the View.  I'm trying to change the view to also be IQueryable, but the view gives compile errors on 'Type or namespace 'IQueryable' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)'

```
<!-- Index.cshtml -->
@using System.Linq    <!-- flags as 'previously appears in namespace' -->
@model IEnumerable<MyTableName> <!-- compiles and displays -->
@model IQueryable<MyTableName> <!-- doesn't compile, throws exception -->
```

All my projects are 4.5.2.   I am a relative newbie to MVC/EF.  I am referencing System.Core.dll in both my web app and my data project.

When I run, I get the following exception: error CS1061: 'IQueryable' does not contain a definition for 'MyTableName' and no extension method 'MyTableName' accepting a first argument of type 'IQueryable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I want IQueryable because 1) there's a lot of data and 2) I'll be using Infragistics controls (which are NOT currently in the page).  I want to only get the data I need.  (I'm a total newbie to Infragistics but all Infragistics references are out of the page.)

Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: Do not return an `IQueryable` from your controllers full stop. Call `ToList()` on it before you return it, otherwise you will run into SELECT n + 1 issues. Then set the `@model` to `List<MyTableName>`

Comment: can you provide full error message?

Comment: can you also explain why you need IQueryable in your view?

Comment: @Grundy answered in edit, thanks!

Comment: @LiranBo answered in edit, thanks!

Comment: as you can see: https://dotnetfiddle.net/3LRw3O `IQueryable<T>` work ok, so something wrong somewhere else. Can you provide a bit more info?

Comment: @Grundy if I knew what more information to provide, I'd provide it.  :(

Comment: you might want to try add the complete namespace, e.g. @model IQueryable<MYAssembly.MyModel.MyTableName> (have not tried out Infragistics, but according to their demo code that could help)

Comment: @Cindy, IQueryable is about expression building, IEnumerable deals with instances. For views, you should be using IEnumerable/instances. 

It's worth noting that MVC uses `dynamic` quite a bit; viewState, viewBags.. but the framework casts the uses of these dynamic objects to `IDictionary<string,object>` to avoid reflection overhead as it **enumerates** over the types. `object`, here, is expected to be an instance.

Comment: at any rate, your issue is a bit peculiar, and seems to stem on your reference to `System.Linq`, or at least the generic types... My guess is that you have improperly named one of your project namespaces `Linq`.. or something to that effect..

Comment: Try doing `@model System.Linq.IQueryable<MyTableName>` and see if it resolves properly

Comment: I suppose it's worth referencing (for general purpose emphasis), that `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<T>` are not defined in the `System.Linq` namspace (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq(v=vs.110).aspx), and are not part of `System.Core` **dll** and **assembly**.  So your issue is likely in that reference, since `IEnumerable<T>` compiles. Also, your exception does not indicate that your problem is in referencing your type, `MyTableName`, fully qualified or otherwise. For, it would indicate that `MyTableName` is *not* defined.

Comment: @BrettCaswell, Thanks for all your suggestions and your careful reading of my question.  :)  Unfortunately, I've tried your suggestions and they don't work.  Yes, it certainly does seem as if I've got something mis-referenced somewhere, but I haven't been able to find it.  The solution is very new - maybe I need to rework it to use IEnumerable and IQueryable as others have suggested...

Comment: @CindyH, I couldn't reproduce this, for it wouldn't let me install 4.5.2 (from the web installer) as it indicated I'm already using it or later version (4.6, which is odd because I'm using VS2013 Express here)... which version of System.Core are you referencing in your assembly references? for instance, my **4.5.1** references are in ***"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1\System.Core.dll"***

Comment: Additionally, the **runtime version** of the assembly is **v4.0.30319**, the "Version" is **4.0.0.0**.. mine is signed (of course)...is that what you have?.. try specifying it as **"Specific Version" = "true"** (also, the **alias** is simply **global**)

Comment: ah.. although it wasn't noted, it seems I was attempting to download and install the 4.5.2 Runtime; I was able to download the proper 4.5.2 installer (Developer Pack) from http://getdotnet.azurewebsites.net/target-dotnet-platforms.html# (which is linked to by visual studio, project > properties window > 'Application' tab > 'Target Framework' combobox > 'install other frameworks')... anyway, **System.Core.dll** in **"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Core.dll"** seems exactly the same as **4.5.1** (didn't run a checksum though).

Comment: I couldn't get the issue to occur even with a de-reference to System.Core in my project/solution.. (and the removal of all files in bin and obj/debug).. which is infact what I think you should do here.. select 'Show All Files' in your solution explorer (which selecting your project(s)).. delete all files in bin folder, and delete all files in 'bin/debug', remove your reference to System.Core.dll in your project reference. Clear solution/project and re-build project.

Comment: actually, I've had to perform this same, explicit deletion, to clear embedded metadata issues before (specifically the three schema files generated by edmx - entity framework database first implementation were giving false positives).

Comment: also, have you modified your machine.config file at some point?

Answer (score 0):

In `VIEWS\web.config` (not the web.config in the root directory) add the namespace `System.Linq` to the following section:

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    ...
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
         <add namespace="System.Linq" />
```

Comment: I was all excited, but this made no difference.  System.Linq was not previously a namespace in my Views\web.config, I added it, cleaned the solution, stopped the website in IIS Express, closed and reopened Visual Studio, rebuilt (still had the red squiggly compile error) and ran (with the same exception which I have now added to the original question).

Comment: CindyH it could be because you are not using a namespace for referencing the model class?

Like IQueryable<MainNamespace.Models.MyTableName>

Note: You should do all transformation Logic and Queries on the Controller side, not because you can do it on the view means that you should, most of the times i see people with ASPX background doing this kind of stuff that violates the MVC pattern (no offense, just saying).

Regards

Comment: @darkndream Thanks.  I actually am using a namespace for referencing the model class - but would that be different for IEnumerable vs IQueryable?  I'm not offended - I appreciate the tip! I do realize that wanting to do CRUD logic within the MVC page violates the MVC pattern.  Unfortunately, I'm new at the company as well, and I've already rocked the boat too much.

Comment: Since Iqueryable does implement Ienumerable you can pass the resulting object to the view. But inside of the view you will be able only to use ienumerable.methods. as it is intended to be.

Comment: hmm.. `IQueryable<T>` doesn't **implement** anything, for it is an interface. it **inherits** `IEnumerable<T>`. There are two things to consider here, the first is that an object instance that implements `IQueryable<T>`, and thus becomes and `instanceof` `IQueryable<T>`, does not automatically become an `instanceof` `IEnumerable<T>`. Thus there is no implicit conversion of `IQueryable<T>` to `IEnumerable<T>`. This brings up the second consideration: Extension Methods. `IQueryable<T>` does not inherit the extension methods of `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: actually, forget the last consideration.. it's actually difficult for me to qualify whether `IQueryable<T>` does or does not inherit the extension methods of it's underline type `IEnumerable<T>`.  They certainly aren't exposed via intellisense, but that's just type derivative.

But in practice, (for instance - creating an extension method yourself on any particular `IQueryable<T>`) you may have to qualify the full method using `System.Linq.Enumerable.<Method>` and/or `System.linq.Queryable.<Method>`.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the IEnumerable in your view since it makes the IQueryable object to be executed.

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.iqueryable(v=vs.110).aspx):
"The IQueryable interface inherits the IEnumerable interface so that if it represents a query, the results of that query can be enumerated. Enumeration causes the expression tree associated with an IQueryable object to be executed."

Comment: I agree, but this doesn't really address the issue of the OP, it circumvents it.  It's better to state it as a comment, like everyone else has.  The OP's issue here revolves around referencing namespaces and types.